# Ensure that user input is double on multiple inputs

Tags: c#, parsing, double, console-application, user-input

In C#, Console, I am prompting the user to enter inputs and I want to make sure that those are double and if not, will then prompt the user to re-enter the value.

Here's my code:

```
    public static void userExpenses() {

        Console.Write("Enter your Monthly Income (before deductions): ");
        Program.Income = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Write("Enter your estimated monthly tax: ");
        Program.Deductions[0] = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Write("Enter monthly expenses for 1. Groceries: ");
        Program.Deductions[1] = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Write("Enter monthly expenses for 2. Water + Lights: ");
        Program.Deductions[2] = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Write("Enter monthly expenses for 3. Transportation: ");
        Program.Deductions[3] = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Write("Enter monthly expenses for 4. Phone/s: ");
        Program.Deductions[4] = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Write("Enter monthly expenses for 5. Other: ");
        Program.Deductions[5] = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Use decimal, not a floating point type for monetary amounts. To answer your question: use a loop and `TryParse`. Maybe put it in a method.

Comment: I just typed "c# validate double" into a search engine and the first result was another question on this very site that answers your question. You need to make an effort for yourself before asking others to do for you.

Comment: @John Do you mind to mark it as duplicate then?

Comment: @John My question is more for efficiency purposes, I want to know if there is a way to do it without having to do a whole while loop for each input.

Comment: That's why you factor code duplication into a method (see my answer).

Comment: Your question doesn't say that. Your question should state what it is that you want to know. Assume that too many words is better than not enough.

Comment: Well: ask, read, check , return or loop, that's as efficient as you can get. In terms of DRY principle, you don't code that explicitly for each input. You make _one_ method, that does it, which you can parameterise. That's how it's done. In quite any programming language.

Answer (score 2):

You could use something like:

```
public static decimal GetValueFromUser(string query)
{
    Console.Write(query);
    while(!decimal.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out decimal result))
    {
        Console.Write("Error: Input was not a number. Try again:")
    }
    return result;
}
```

Usage:

```
Program.Income = GetValueFromUser("Enter your Monthly Income (before deductions): ");
```

Mind: I used `decimal` since floating point types are really bad when dealing with money. You can chose to use `double` or `int`, though. They, too have a `TryParse` method.